# Complex SQL query with group by and having in condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the table test below:

```
------------------------------
id | active| record
------------------------------
3  | O     | 2015-10-16
3  | O     | 2015-10-15
3  | N     | 2015-10-14
4  | N     | 2015-10-15
4  | O     | 2015-10-14
```

I want to do an update on the table on the lines with:
- An id having the column active = 'O' more than once.
- Among theses lines having active = 'O' more than once, the update shall change the value of active to 'N', except for the one with max(record), which will stay with active = 'O'.

In my example, the id having the column active = 'O' more than once is id = 3.

```
id |active | record
------------------------------
3  | O     | 2015-10-16
3  | O     | 2015-10-15
3  | N     | 2015-10-14
```

I want to have this result:

```
id |active | record
------------------------------
3  | O     | 2015-10-16
3  | N     | 2015-10-15
3  | N     | 2015-10-14
```

I tried this query, but there is an error:

```
update test as t1,
(select id
from test
where active = 'O'
group by id
having count(*) > 1) as t2
set t1.actif = 'N'
where t1.record != max(t2.record);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `active` varchar(1), `record` date)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `active`, `record`)
VALUES
    (3, 'O', '2015-10-16'),
    (3, 'O', '2015-10-15'),
    (3, 'N', '2015-10-14'),
    (4, 'N', '2015-10-15'),
    (4, 'O', '2015-10-14')
;
```

This query

```
UPDATE 
t
JOIN (
  SELECT 
  id, MAX(record) AS max_record
  FROM 
  t
  WHERE active = 'O'
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sq ON t.id = sq.id
SET t.active = IF(t.record = sq.max_record, 'O', 'N');
```

produces this result:

```
+------+--------+------------+
| id   | active | record     |
+------+--------+------------+
|    3 | O      | 2015-10-16 |
|    3 | N      | 2015-10-15 |
|    3 | N      | 2015-10-14 |
|    4 | N      | 2015-10-15 |
|    4 | O      | 2015-10-14 |
+------+--------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with something like this

```
select ID, 
count(*) Counted, 
max(record) record 
into #TempTable from Table
where Active = 'O'
group by ID

Update tab
set tab.Active = 'N'
from Table tab
join #tempTable temp on tab.ID = temp.ID
where temp.Counted > 1 and 
tab.record != temp.record

drop table #tempTable
```

Basically, you just counting Os while grabbing ID and max record into temp table and after that you doing the update, also this code might need some changes as i just took a glance to point you toward direction i would do it